# there is something like didAppear for a cell in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem with my textViews, because when they appear, always appear scrolled to the bottom, I read here that is a problem that occurs when the textview has constraints, and the solution is set the isScrollEnabled to false and in the didAppear set to true, but because the superview of my textview is a cell in a collectionView, I don't know how to solve this

BTW, I'm using swift 3 and XCode 8

edit: Sorry, I'm not using a nib

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to override `prepareForReuse` to make any changes before the cell will be visible.

Comment: I think that the solution you posted looks more complicated than it should be. Don't know the way you are creating your cells, but I'm pretty sure you could easily have a reference to your UITextView, and when preparing to reuse the cell, set it to scroll to the top, instead of doing changes and then reload the cell in cellForItem, extra work. Suggest you to check on the lifecycle of the cells in the collection and table views.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this, but i did a lot of things, i'm new in ios programming and i don't understand very well a lot of things, but this is how i did it.

To make a textView scrolls to top in a collectionView in my view controller i search for any textViews there and when find it, i set the contentOffset, for the first cell i used the viewdidlayoutsubviews, but for the other cell i had to use the willDisplay and didEndDisplaying, making exactly the same:

`let container = collectionView.subviews[0].subviews
        for v in container {
            if let fView = v as? UITextView {
                fView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0)
            }
        }`

I enter to the cell subviews directly, and set is contentOffset, but the trick is to reload the cell in the cellForItemAt, just like this:

```
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

and thats it, i hope this helps some one and thanks for your answers.